# MediaWiki extension: get sections or structured article text from WikiPage/ParserOutput

Tags: php, parsing, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I am using the following to get a WikiPage and ParserOutput:

`$parserOutput = WikiPage::factory(Title::newFromText('sometitle'))
->getParserOutput(new ParserOptions());`

Then, I can see the sections in the article:

`print_r($parserOutput->getSections());`

But, this just gives me a section title and information about the order/TOC level.

**How can I go from here to getting the text content of the section?**

Alternative question: how can I get *structured* data from an article? That is, I want to go from an article title to an object with a map of sections to text.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a nice way. For a hacky one, you can look at how MobileFrontend [does it](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-MobileFrontend/blob/master/includes/api/ApiMobileView.php#L493-L541).